# Service resource not appearing on Gantt chart in Field service lightning

Tags: field-service-lightning

So as title suggests i am not able to see Service resources in the gantt chart in FSL,although

1. There is no filter applied in resources filter section.
2. Service resources are having matching territory and matching skills.
3. Service resource is assigned territory and that territory is selected in dispatcher console.

[image: Dispatcher console]

4. Service appointment appears in service appointment list but no service resources are displayed.Service resource is associated with particular SA.

[image: Service appointment list]

5. I have selected the territory in territory filter related to below Service appointment.

Comment: Does the user assigned to `Service Resource` record have the required permissions? Like FSL Resource/FSL Resource Permissions/FSL Mobile. Basically `FSL Mobile License` and `FSL Resource License`

Comment: @HemantJain Yes the issue was with permissions. I assigned FSL resource permissions and also FSL resource licence to the user and then it worked thanks a lot!!.Please move this to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Service Resource visibility also depends on the FSL Resource permission assignments on the `User` record associated to `Service Resource` record.

Basically a technician user(associated to `Service Resource` record) should have the permissions `FSL Mobile License` and `FSL Resource License`